# regular expression for file parsing

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm writing a file parser, and I want to know how to match the entire phrase :

```
Pool {
```

And

```
Name = File
```

by using regular expression? There can be more than one space before/after all words.

I tried  `(\W|^)Pool\s{(\W|$)` to match the first but it doesn't work. Anyone could help?

Comment: What part is constant and which is dynamic?

Comment: Keep things simple: `^\W*Pool\s*{\s*\W*$`

Comment: @stribizhev the first one is constant, the second one "file" is dynamic and I will pass the name as an argument in Java

Comment: @arkascha It works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mF0eR7/3)

```
/\s*Pool\s+\{\s*/g
```

---

The second: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qJ7pY4/1)

```
/\s*Name\s+=\s+File\s/g*
```

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect.

Comment: But strangely it does not run in Java. Even though I changed \ for \\

Comment: Use `\s*Pool\s+\{\s*` for example.. without / and /g

Answer (score 1):

`{` is a metacharacter and needs to be escaped.